# Dynamic memory allocation "delete"

Tags: c++, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation, delete-operator

If I allocated a memory location for an `int` object dynamically as follows:

`int *x = new int;`

After done with it, and want to free the memory on the heap, I will do the following:

`delete x;`

Now, if I did **not** do the following:

`x = NULL;`

Will `x` be pointing to *another* address? **UPDATE:** `another` instead of `many`

Say I didn't do `x = NULL` and made **another** `delete x;`, what will happen?

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c%2B%2B-faq-lite/freestore-mgmt.html#faq-16.2

Answer (score 6):

1. Anything you do with `x` (apart from `= NULL` - which is, imo, bad practice) after you delete it is undefined.
2. double-delete = disaster.

> Note: some runtime systems will
>   protect you from certain very simple
>   cases of double delete. Depending on
>   the details, you might be okay if you
>   happen to be running on one of those
>   systems and if no one ever deploys
>   your code on another system that
>   handles things differently and if you
>   are deleting something that doesn't
>   have a destructor and if you don't do
>   anything significant between the two
>   deletes and if no one ever changes
>   your code to do something significant
>   between the two deletes and if your
>   thread scheduler (over which you
>   likely have no control!) doesn't
>   happen to swap threads between the two
>   deletes and if, and if, and if. So
>   back to Murphy: since it can go wrong,
>   it will, and it will go wrong at the
>   worst possible moment.

https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt

Answer (score 5):

After the `delete`, the pointer will typically still contain the address of the (now free) memory. The second `delete` gives undefined behavior, so don't do that.

Answer (score 2):

It will invoke undefined behavior. If you don't do `x=NULL` then `x` will be pointing to an invalid memory location which if you try to use will cause undefined behavior.

Comment: But, when I do `delete`, am I not deleting the `pointer` itself? How is it as you say `If you don't do x=NULL then x will be pointing to an invalid memory location'? Thanks

Comment: @user588855: Lets say `x` was 0x11111111  before deletion. So when you do `delete x;` this memory location is free. But since you didn't set `x` to `NULL` it is still having the value `0x11111111` which is a freed memory location. Trying to read/write into this location using `*x` or `x->` will invoke undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

type:

```
int main(){
  int* i = new int;
  std::cout << i << std::endl;
  delete i;
  std::cout << i << std::endl;
  delete i;
}
```

result:

0x8e19008

0x8e19008

** glibc detected ** ./a.out: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x08e19008 ***

as you see, the address stays the same, but the second delete ends in a runtime error. behaviour may in detail depend on environment, but as a general rule it will not work.

Comment: That last sentence is not necessarily true: Some compilers will "protect" you from doing this, so it might *appear* to "work". But it's still undefined behavior, and it's still a bad idea. Testing it is not the right way to get an answer here.

Comment: @Code Gray: That's not testing, it's demonstrating. That the first sentence is not necessarily true is why I said "may depend on environment".

Answer (score 1):

calling delete on already deleted memory will cause undefined behaviour. Generally, your program will crash.

After deleting x, where it will be pointing is "compiler dependent". Most of the compilers will just let it point to where it was, before delete was called. But that memory address is no more valid, and hence should not be called.

For this same reason, "delete this" must be used very judiciously and carefully, if at all needed. :-)

Comment: When you say: `calling delete on already deleted memory will cause undefined behaviour.`. Isn't it the `pointer` which is deleted and not the `memory`? Thanks

Comment: @user: neither is being deleted, per se. The memory is being freed, which means that your program tells the operating system: "okay, thanks for the chunk of memory, I'm done using it!" and your program no longer has read/write access to it.

Answer (score 1):

The secondth delete is undefined.

As a side note, there are tools to detect a double deletion. One of the best one around is [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).